# Mac Installer Certificates

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I'm at the point where I'm ready to submit an app - an Apple doesn't elaborate much on how to sign and submit apps. I have both the WWDRCA certificate and one I created but am at a loss on where to put them.. do I add them via drag n' drop into XCode? Why do I need the WWDRCA? Anyone have any info on this? Would be GREATLY appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you have correctly installed the Installer, Developer and WWDR certs in your Keychain.

In Xcode, edit your target build settings and under 'Code signing entity' and select your Developer certificate. Then build your app using 'Build and Archive'. Finally, open Organizer (via Window menu) to verify and submit your app.

At least, that's the theory. I agree that it's tricky. The Apple Developer Forums have several instructive postings about the potential pitfalls. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I ended up spending a couple hours just figuring that (fairly) simple process out myself because Apple's current documentation is incredibly vague. But now it's a waiting game haha. But thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Dang, I missed that it's about the Mac App Store, my post is about iOS... For the Mac App Store, there's also a [document from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/documents/submitting.html) and a [checklist with links](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/checklist/). That checklist seems like a good starting point for all the relevant information.

**Original iOS related post:**

If you log in to the [Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/my/overview/index.action), Apple explains in detail how to get and use a certificate (now even with videos). Right when you login to the portal, see the right column. Or click on the *"Certificates"* link on the left and then on the *"How to"* tab. It's step-by-step guide with screenshots. Also, see the *"Provisioning"* section in the left meny, again click the *"How to"* tab. For submitting, see the *"Distribution"* section in the menu on the left. If you still have specific question after reading/watching that material, go ahead and ask.

You need the WWDR CA certificate so that your keychain and Xcode can actually validate your certificate. Certificates are signed by other certificates and form a chain of trust. But there has to be a start, and that is the CA certificate for which you first explicitly state *"Yes, I trust this certificate"* and thus all certificates that were signed by it.

This is also how your browser works with HTTPS: your browser comes with a bunch of CA certificates that it trusts by default, for example the CA certificate from Verisign. And if your browser then sees a certificate that was signed by Verisign it knows it can trust that website since it already trusts the Verisign CA.

Comment: thanks for those links - however i actually already scoured through those haha.